# How to use require on client side js with browserify

Tags: node.js, browserify

I've created some module which performs certain task and I am exporting it and I want to use it on client side js. My folder structure is this

[image]

I want to be able to use const createRoomId = require("../../services/createRoomId"); in private-chat.js file but I am getting require is not defined. I've installed browserify and tried this

```
browserify ../../services/createRoomId.js -o bundle.js
```

in console which creates bundle.js file. I've also added script bundle.js to html.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the "require" method, which is not defined in the client-side (Browser). Because the "require" method belongs to Nodejs.

you can handle this issue using browserify as below. but the best approach is using script tags and setting type attribute as "module", and using ES6 module import/export!

1. npm i -g browserify
2. browserify main.js > bundle.js

But, the recommended approach is this one. In HTML, include the main JavaScript file using attribute type="module"

```html
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
```

And in the createRoomId.js file, include another file like this:

```js
  import { myFunction } from './createRoomId.js';
    ...
    // alert(hello());
```

Inside the included file (createRoomId.js), you must export the function/class that you will import:

```js
export function hello() {
    return "Hello World";
}
```